# How to create an additional login page?

Tags: 8

I want to create another login page, for example `www.example.com/user-admin`. But without deleting the existing one.

Or, as an alternative, I want to be able to display the login forum anywhere.

How can I do that?

Comment: It is quite possible to create a custom module that provides a new route that uses the existing user login form class, or you could even write your own login form class that adds the same "login validators" to the validation. And it is possible to add the user login block to any page in any available region on your site via admin/structure/blocks. This question is too broad to provide an accurate, non-opinionated answer, and you should try to provide more details as to what you have personally tried to do.